# User selectable SQL Server Compact database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, openfiledialog

We're creating an application that stores data in a number of tables using an SQL Server Compact `.sdf` file.

When the program starts, we want to present the user the option of working from an existing database file that already contains data, or create a new empty database file. We've created the `.sdf` file using the database explorer in Visual Studio, so I presume it's being stored with the bin files by default.

Two questions:

- How do we use the `OpenFileDialog` to allow the user to select a database and modify the data connection accordingly?
- When the user decides to start with a new database, will the program remember the database structure we created with the database explorer, or do we have to recreate the tables, fields and connections from scratch in the program?

ThanX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you intentionally want users to be able to access DB files from any arbitrary location on their computer, you'd be better off storing the DB files in an application directory and letting users pick the DB from a simple ListView (which you would populate by iterating through all the DB files in your application's data directory or sub-directory).

For your second question, you should create a template database file with the correct tables, fields etc. but no data, and embed this as a resource in your application. To create a new database for the user, you would copy this resource to an actual file location (with the new DB's file name).

Comment: I like the approach you suggested of storing the various DB in the application directory, and allowing them to select one, or create a new one.

I'm still not sure how to change the active file being used by the various queries. I can't seem to find the database itself in the namespace of the project. I can view the properties of the database as shown in the solution explorer, but can't seem to modify it's properties programmatically.

Comment: The connection string that you use to open a `Connection` object should contain the path to the local DB; to change the "active" DB, you just need to build a new connection string and open a new Connection object.

Comment: Regarding your second question: I dunno, since I'm not sure how you've set this up in your project. You'd probably do well to ask another question about this here on SO.